# Numerical Divergence of a Tensor Field in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: numerics, tensor

I want to calculate the divergence of a rank-2 tensor field $$\nabla \cdot T$$ defined on the surface of a sphere in spherical coordinates. As an example, let the field be given as follows :

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

LAT = 100
LONG = 100

tensor_field = np.array([np.random.rand(LAT,LONG) for i in range(9)])
```

here, each one of the 9 entries corresponds to one component in spherical coordinates of the rank-2 tensor.

If it were a rank-1 tensor field (a vector field), I could brute force my way by manually converting each component to Cartesian basis, and calculate the divergence as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970477/compute-divergence-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Is there a simpler way for higher rank tensor fields?

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! Have you checked: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates ?

Comment: Have you tried to write down the contraction of the covariant derivative with the tensor in index notation?